# Method is undefined for the type Double

Tags: java

In Eclipse, it's giving me the error that the method is undefined for the type `Double` but the return is a `Double`. And when I compile it says that it cannot find symbol `getF`.

```
public Double getF()
{
    if (cof == 'c' || cof == 'C')
    {
        converted = (deg * 1.8) + 32;
        converted = Math.round(converted*10.0)/10.0;
        dConv = converted;
        return dConv;
    }

    dDeg = deg;
    return dDeg;
```

I get the error in this equals method when I try to use the `getF` method.

```
public boolean equals(double degrees)
{
    test = degrees;
    dTest = test;
    if (this == dTest.getF())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm running code against a tester. This is one of the tests:

```
     System.out.println("Test case 18: equals test 1.");
     System.out.println();
     t1.set(100, 'C');
     t2.set(212, 'F');
     System.out.println("T1 = 100 degrees C.");
     System.out.println("T2 = 212 degrees F.");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Here are the two temperatures " + "converted to degrees C:");
     t1.writeC();
     t2.writeC();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Verify results: should be true.");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Hit 'y' to continue.");
     junk = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println();
```

And this is the constructor:

```
public Temperature (double degrees, char type)
{
    deg = degrees;
    cof = type;
}
```

Comment: Show the actual compiler error, @lx0103.

Comment: `Double` doesn't have a `getF()` method, and a primitive `double` has no methods. Also, `Object.equals(Object)`.

Comment: You appear to be trying to call a method off of a double primitive type, or a Double wrapper type -- why? That doesn't make sense -- please explain.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to "override" something that doesn't exist? The `getF` method seems to be incomplete (or incorrect) as well.

Comment: And if you show the entire compilable test-case we will be able to help you much more efficiently, @lx0103.

Comment: Did you mean to write `if (this.getF() == dTest)`? Also, beware using `==` when comparing Objects, and `Double` is an Object. Any reason you're boxing your `double` values?

Comment: I boxed it because I thought it would help with it having issues with it not being defined by Double.

Comment: And if you box it, it's an object, so == is references not raw value, and anyway comparing doubles directly has rounding problems